# Redirecting using cookies

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, cookies

I've made a web site, and on my index page there are two links. One leads to /eng/index.htm and second to /hr/index.htm. I've also added a "Switch to" option on every /eng/ page and every /hr/ page to switch to other language.

I'm trying to make cookie that remembers users choice and next time he goes to index page it redirects him to the index page of the language he has chosen the first time.
And also if it's possible to change to cookie if users has clicked on "Switch to" link.

I've tried with many java scripts and suggestions from this site but no luck. :(

I've added this to my language index pages:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
var d = new Date() 
var dMonth = d.getTime() + 30*24*60*60*1000 
d.setTime(dMonth) 
document.cookie = 'startPage=' + location.href + '; expires=' + d.toGMTString() 
function deleteCookie(){ 
var d = new Date(2000,1,1) 
document.cookie = 'startPage=' + location.href + '; expires=' + d.toGMTString() 
} 
</script>
```

And this to my index page:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
 var c = document.cookie.split(';') 
 if(c.length >0){ 
 for(m=0;m<c.length;m++){ 
if(c[m].indexOf('startPage')>-1){ 
location.replace(c[m].split('=')[1]) 
} 
} 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Show what you've attempted, and we'll try to help fix it. But we don't just pump out some code. Not anymore. There's too many freeloaders out there who expect other people to do their jobs for them.

Comment: Where are the semicolons?? Are you getting any errors in your console??

Comment: What semicolons? No errors in console.

When I'm testing it with Firefox on desktop it works, but when it's uploaded to the web it doesn't.
On Chrome it's not working on either.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add domain=example.com; too your cookie, because you will be setting it on the second page, but reading it on the index page. To make switch to thing work, just run your delete cookie function and create a new one with the corresponding url.